# What does 1[d=b] mean?

Tags: c, obfuscation

I was working through the 160 byte BrainFuck code trying to figure out what things do, and I cant seem to figure out what 1[d=b] does.

```
s[99],*r=s,*d,c;main(a,b){char*v=1[d=b];for(;c=*v++%93;)for(b=c&2,b=c%7?a&&(c&17
?c&1?(*r+=b-1):(r+=b-1):syscall(4-!b,b,r,1),0):v;b&&c|a**r;v=d)main(!c,&a);d=v;}
```

Heres the code, its about midway through the first line
http://j.mearie.org/post/1181041789/brainfuck-interpreter-in-2-lines-of-c

I'm not asking what it does in that context but what 1[] does in the first place.

Thanks =)

Comment: Just a guess, but if `d` represents an array (and I'm not completely sure, since I don't know BrainF*ck), then I suspect that `1[d=b]` returns the second element of `d` (after assigning `b` to `d`).

Comment: This isn't a dup _per se_ but I know there are many other questions dealing with the `arr[1] == 1[arr]` thing. Alas, it is a tricky thing to Google.

Comment: Only Jon Skeet can parse this code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In C, there is no difference between `x[7]` and `7[x]`. They both equate to `*(x+7)` (and `*(7+x)` since addition is commutative) which means the seventh element of the `x` array.

In this particular case (`1[d=b]`), you first assign the current value of `b` to `d`, then calculate `1[d]` which is the same as `d[1]`.

By doing it this way (`offset[base]` rather than `base[offset]`), it allows you to combine it with the assignment, otherwise you'd need:

```
d = b; char *v = d[1];
```

---

I suppose I shouldn't need to tell you that this is actually very *bad* code, as evidenced by the fact that you have to think very hard about what it means. Better code would be almost instantly decipherable.

Comment: I think an alternative, but not sure if more understandable, would be  

  `char *v = (d=b)[1];`

Answer (score 6):

It indexes into the array/pointer `d` (which was just assigned the value of `b`). It is equivalent to

```
d=b;
char*v=d[1];
```

In c, arrays and pointers can be handled the same way in many respects; most notably that one can use pointer arithmetic the same way on both. `d[1]` is equivalent to `*(d + 1)`, which is trivially equivalent to `*(1 + d)` - which in turn is equivalent to `1[d]`!

Using the index notation may be more typical for array types, but (especially in obfuscated code contests ;-) both can be used on either type. Don't use such tricks in real, production code though... as you can testify, it can make future maintainers' life difficult :-(

Answer (score 3):

```
a[b] is *(a + b)
b[a] is *(b + a)
```

So

```
a[b] is b[a]
```

And

```
1[a] is a[1]
```

`v=1[d=b]` is `d=b; v=d[1];`